# Is there any method/function in the sublime or sublime_plugin module that can return what programming language is being used

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

i'm trying to build a plugin for sublime and want to know the programming language being used by the user in their current working file.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the [API Reference](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) there's a `view.settings().get('syntax')` that would give you the syntax or language.